# globally lipschitz condition of the equation for the inverse function implies uniqueness?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$g'(\theta)=-(2-\theta-2g(\theta))\frac{f(\theta)}{1-F(\theta)}\equiv G(g, \theta)$, $\theta\in[0,1]$

with assumptions

(i)$F(\cdot)$ is a continuous c.d.f. and

(ii)$g(\cdot)$ is continuous and strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$.

I can analytically solve this equation by using integrating factor

$L(\theta,x)=(\frac{1-F(\theta)}{1-F(x)})^2 $ and integrating from 1 to x

$g(x)=\frac{1}{[1-F(x)]^2}\left([1-F(1)]^2g(1)+\int_x^1(2-\theta)(1-F(\theta)) f(\theta)d\theta\right)$

The boundary condition is implied by that expression from left continuity at $\theta=1$,  $g(1-)=1/2$?[not sure about this]

The problem is that at upper boundary point $\theta=1$,    $g'(1)=-\infty$, which implies $G(g, \theta)$ is not locally lipschitz in $g$?

Denote $h(\cdot)$ the inverse function of $g(\cdot)$ on $[0,1]$.

$h'(y)=- \frac{1}{2-h(y)-y}\frac{1-F(h(y))}{f(h(y))}\equiv H(h, y)$

Since $h'(1/2)$ is bounded at $h(1/2)=1$,  $H(h, y)$ satisfies locally Lipschitz in $h$ at $\theta=1$?

Does this implies $g(\cdot)$ has a unique global solution? Thanks.

Comment: The Lipschitz condition for uniqueness does not refer to the solution being Lipschitz. It refers to the right-hand side of equation being Lipschitz as a function of the unknown. The original form of the equation is *linear*, which should make the analysis of uniqueness simpler than  your form with $h$. The thing you really should focus on is the precise formulation of the initial value problem. You can't prove uniqueness for an initial value problem if you can't state the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. The problem now is that the initial value is endogneous determined (since I assume the unknown $g(\cdot)$ is continuous everywhere on entire interval $[0,1]$), so  right continuity of $g(\cdot)$ at $\theta=1$ implies the unique initial value?

Comment: I seems to understand what you mentioned. So does it mean   $g'(\cdot)$ is not bounded at $\theta=1$ is sufficient for $G(g,\theta)$ is not locally Lipschitz in $g$, while $h'(\cdot)$ is bounded at $y=1/2$ is not sufficient for $H(h,y)$ is locally Lipschitz in $h$?

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the inverse function does not help. In the equation
$$
h'(y)=- \frac{1}{2-h(y)-2y}\frac{1-F(h(y))}{f(h(y))}
$$
the right hand side is not a Lipschitz function of $h$ when $(y,h)\approx (1/2,1)$.

---

Instead of trying to squeeze into a general theorem, we can prove uniqueness directly. Multiplying both sides of the equation by the integrating factor $(1-F)^2$, we get 
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\left( (1-F(\theta))^2 g(\theta) \right) = -(2-\theta) (1-F(\theta)) f(\theta) \tag1$$ 
It follows that 
$$  (1-F(\theta))^2 g(\theta)   = - \int(2-\theta) (1-F(\theta)) f(\theta) \,d\theta \tag2$$ 
This is not just *some* solution; this is a statement about any solution that the equation may have.

If $g$ is continuous, the left side of (2) is zero at $\theta=1$. This determines the antiderivative on the right of (2). That's it, the uniqueness is proved.

---

This does not actually show *existence* of a continuous $g$ that satisfies the equation. But if the function $1-F$ has decent behavior at $\theta=1$, without crazy changes of the rate of decay, then the antiderivative in (2) will decay like $(1-F)^2$ as $\theta\to 1$.